# How to rename foreign key constraint | MySql 5.6, InnoDB

Tags: mysql, constraints, innodb, database-indexes

I need to rename fk constraints (drop all fk, create new ones), but MySql (cuz InnoDB engine) created indexes for these constraints. 
Do I need to drop indexes manually? Or it will lead to issues? Please, somebody describe me this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not lead to issues.

Adding an FK *should* discover that there is already a sufficient index and not add a second one.  Even if it adds a redundant index, little harm is done.

I wonder -- Why do you care what the constraint names are?

From 5.6 doc:  "For ALTER TABLE, unlike CREATE TABLE, ADD FOREIGN KEY ignores index_name if given and uses an automatically generated foreign key name. As a workaround, include the CONSTRAINT clause to specify the foreign key name: `ADD CONSTRAINT name FOREIGN KEY (....) ..`" and "Adding and dropping a foreign key in the same ALTER TABLE statement is supported for ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE but not for ALTER TABLE ... ALGORITHM=COPY."

My point in bringing that up is that `ALTER` *usually* runs faster if you throw all the changes to a table into a single statement.  But `DROP` + `ADD` is disallowed in the `COPY` case.

Comment: Because I renamed table and trying to load dump (need by requirements) and faced with duplicate foreign key issue. And this is not allowed just to drop old table by grants.

Comment: Turn off the FKs, LOAD, then turn on.